# How to convert JSONObject to a JSONArray?

Tags: android, node.js, json, express, backend

Recently,I got the problem when I tried to implement a comment function in an Android APP.

The definition of comments in user.js is as follow

```
comnents: [{

    ownerID: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    commenterID: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    commenterName: String,
    content: {
        type: String,
        require: true,

    }
}],
```

And I have a request like that:

```
{
    "_id":"60d204d6efc6c70022b08dc4",
    "comments":[
        {
            "ownerID":"60d204d6efc6c70022b08dc4",
            "commenterID":"60d205afefc6c70022b08dc8",
            "commenterName":"Bob",
            "content":"Hello World!"
        },
        {
            "ownerID":"60d204d6efc6c70022b08dc4",
            "commenterID":"60d20892efc6c70022b08dd2",
            "commenterName":"Alice",
            "content":"Hello Earth!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my API

```
router.post("/writecomment",jsonParser,
    async(req,res,next)=>{
        const errors=validationResult(req);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            return res.status(400).json({erros:errors.array()});
        }
        
        User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "_id": req.body._id},
            {
                $set: {
                    comments:req.body.comments
                }
            },
            {overwrite:true},
            function(err,resp){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(resp) {
                    return res.send({
                        msg:' change successfully'
                    });
                }else{
                    return res.status(403).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to change'});
                }
            }
          )


    }
)
```

How do I convert "comments" from request to comments array? Or have a better way to implement this function?

PS: I use Mongoose + Express Framework to develope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const commentArray = [...req.body.comments]`

Will make this for you:

```
[
    {
        "ownerID": "60d204d6efc6c70022b08dc4",
        "commenterID": "60d205afefc6c70022b08dc8",
        "commenterName": "Bob",
        "content": "Hello World!"
    },
    {
        "ownerID": "60d204d6efc6c70022b08dc4",
        "commenterID": "60d20892efc6c70022b08dd2",
        "commenterName": "Alice",
        "content": "Hello Earth!"
    }
]
```

Basically what is happening here is, we are iterating over the response you are getting and saving the result in an array. If you want to learn more about the `...` operator, check out this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax